# How to write a program that reads a C source code and test variables naming convention?

Tags: c, frameworks, naming-conventions

In my work I have the task of writing a simple tool/program that checks the variables naming convention of c source codes.

The naming convention of variables that is being followed here is somehow special and doesn't follow a certain standard (although being close to the Hungarian convention); e.g:

uint16_t (=unsigned short) must begin with „us“

uint8_t (=unsigned char) must begin with „uc“

The logic of analysing the variables naming based on the variable types is not the problem here. I have in mind a plan on how to implement the functions.

I would rephrase my problem in some questions. Please execuse me if they sound naive, as I am still learning:

1. How to start? What is needed to read a source code, in order then to analyze it? I found some tutorials online that talks about building a framework that parses the source code into tokens and then build an AST to analyze the source code tokens, is it the right place to start with?
2. I am thinking of writing this tool using Python, as I found in some [tutorials](https://deepsource.io/blog/introduction-static-code-analysis/) that there are already a very helpful libraries (like AST, IO, tokenize), would you recommend writing it in python to check c source code in general? and how challenging will it be?
3. Is there any tutorial online (or any supporting material) that is related to what I am trying to do here? that would be helpful. If not, could you please provide me with a road map (as simple as possible) in how to do accomplish this task?

p.s: I have read all the related topics/[questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2574416/testing-of-coding-and-naming-conventions-of-c-c-code) and they were not however helpful, as I would like to implement it from scratch rather using an implemented tool.

Comment: 1) Yes, you need to start where compilers/interpreters start, in order to recognize variables in a C source code; 2) Yes, Python will do the trick, and won't be too much complicated; 3) Have a look at [this C compiler written in Python](https://github.com/ShivamSarodia/ShivyC).

Comment: If you are implementing from scratch, shouldn't you be writing in assembly?